# SELECT visitors that have visited more than one place in a day along with the details

Tags: mysql

my mysql table is like:

```
+---------+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| visitId | userId  | locationId | comments              | time                |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|       1 |    3    |     12     | It's a good day here! | 2012-12-12 11:50:12 |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|       2 |    3    |     23     | very beautiful        | 2012-12-12 12:50:12 |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|       3 |    3    |     52     | nice                  | 2012-12-12 13:50:12 |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

witch records visitors' trajectory and some comments on the places visited

**I want to find visitors visited more than one place in a day, along with the specific day AND the places, Not only the count.**

I tried the subquery:

```
mysql> SELECT userId, locationId, time FROM visits 
WHERE (userId,DATE(time)) in (
  SELECT  userNum, Date(weiboTime) from visits GROUP BY userNum, Date(wei
  boTime) Having COUNT(*)>1);
```

And the joint query:

```
mysql> select v2.userId, v1.loacationId, v1.time from visits as v1, visits as
v2 where v1.userId=v2.userId GROUP BY v2.userId, Date(v2.time) HAVING 
COUNT(DISTINCT v2.locationId);
```

I am not sure whether it is correct for the second one. But both of them take too long time. Any suggestions for what should I do?

**UPDATE**

```
mysql> SELECT t.userId, locationId, t.time FROM (
              SELECT userId, time 
              FROM visits GROUP BY userId,Date(time)
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS t, visits 
       WHERE t.userId=visits.userId AND t.time=visits.time;
```

hope this will make myself more clear.

Comment: Why not just [`SELECT  userId
from visits 
GROUP BY userId, Date(time)
Having COUNT(*) > 1;`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/269d8/3)?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I need more precise information, where have this user been to at this specific date. So I need another query to fetch the result as you can see in the first implementation.

Comment: OK, Sorry, What about [**this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/269d8/5)?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Thanks! It works well. I need a little more help for that my final goal is to count the duration of users' staying at some place. This is why I need users that visited more than 1 places in a day. So now I have the intermediate result, and I have modified your suggestions at [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdf70/3) to get the startTime of users at one place taking multiple tweets at one place in consideration. Now I need to subtract the startTime of next  place from each row and take the negation for the final duration. Is this possible using only SQL statements?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal if next row is the same userId, subtract the startTime from this row's startTime and pick the minus other wise this row should be discard... complicated, is it better to do this by programming instead of scratching my head for some implementations using SQL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your queries are including locationId, but your stated goal is to get user/date combos that had more than 1 visit in a day. Here's the sql to get that:

```
select userId, date(time), count(*)
from visits
group by userId, date(time)
having count(*) > 1;
```

**Update:**
To get all visits from user/day combo visits greater than 1:

```
select *
from visits
where (userId, date(time)) in (
    select userId, date(time)
    from visits
    group by userId, date(time)
    having count(*) > 1);
```

Comment: I didn't make myself clear. Actually, after I get the userId and the date that ***this user in this date*** have more than 1 visits, I would like to use this result to fetch exactly where the user have been to in this specific day..

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better suited using a `GROUP BY` in a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) with your count. From [MySQL's count documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html), you can do something like:

```
mysql> SELECT userId, locationId, time, visitCount
       FROM
           (SELECT COUNT(*) as visitCount 
            FROM visits 
            GROUP BY userId)
       WHERE visitCount > 1;
```

I'd assume the slowness you're encountering comes from the `HAVING` and `DISTINCT` in your `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: that is not really what I want. Firstly it is not the total sum of a user that need to be greater than 1, it's actually the sum in one day, so GROUP BY clause should followed by userId,Date(time). Secondly, SELECT userId from this subquery's result is not true, beacuse it has only one field which is the count(*). See my update of this questions, referring to your query

Comment: You should be able to modify my example to further limit by the date. Like I said, you would increase the speed of your queries if you could avoid your `HAVING` and `DISTINCT` usage as they are non-optimal.